# In-house made package and environmental variables link

Tags: python, package, environment-variables

I created a python package for in-house use which relies upon some environmental variables (namely, the user and password to enter an online database). for my company, the convenience of installing a package rather than having it in every  project is significant as the functions inside are used in completely separate projects and maintainability is a primary issue.

so, how do I "link" the package with the environmental variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "link" the two?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll just detail in the readme file what to insert and where. I tried to find a difficult solution when it was really simple and straightforward